# function adds an element to an list and returned sorted

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function where it takes an element and an list and add it to it as long as the list sorted (the smaller to grater) and then sort it again and return it, so I did the function with help of "quickSort" where I sort the list and "isSorted" where is check if a list Is sorted.

so the function first check if the list is sorted if yes it adds the element to it and then after adding it to the list, the list get sorted and returned.

```
insert::a->[a]->[a]
insert n xs 
          | isSorted xs == True = n : xs
insert n xs = quicksort xs


quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]  
quicksort [] = []  
quicksort (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]  
        biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x]  
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted  


isSorted :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
isSorted []       = True
isSorted [x]      = True
isSorted (x:y:xs) = x <= y && isSorted (y:xs)
```

I got this error

```
main.hs:59:13: error:
    * No instance for (Ord a) arising from a use of `isSorted'
      Possible fix:
        add (Ord a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            insert :: forall a. a -> [a] -> [a]
    * In the first argument of `(==)', namely `isSorted xs'
      In the expression: isSorted xs == True
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for `insert':
        isSorted xs == True
   |
59 |           | isSorted xs == True = n : xs
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: BTW you have a bug (once you fix the type signature).  Try `insert 3 [1,2,4,5]`.

Answer (score 4):

`isSorted` requires that its type parameter `a` has an instance of the `Ord` type class. That's how it compares the elements.

Since `insert` calls `isSorted`, `insert` must also require that `a` has an instance of the `Ord` class, so that it can pass that instance to `isSorted` for comparing the elements:

```
insert :: Ord a => a->[a]->[a]
```